# Match all next elements

Tags: jquery

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <a href="#" class="target"></a>
    <div class="block">text</div>
    <div class="block">text</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <a href="#" class="target"></a>
    <div class="block">text</div>
    <div class="block">text</div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".target").click(function() {
    $(this).next('.blocks').slideToggle( "fast" );
});
```

.. works but matches only one (the first) `.block`, not all blocks in the parent element.

Comment: Use `nextAll` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.next()` method get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.

use `.siblings()` or `.nextAll()` selector:

```
$(this).siblings('.blocks').slideToggle( "fast" );
```

or

```
$(this).nextAll('.blocks').slideToggle( "fast" );
```